# A question on inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

I am working on a problem and I got to this point. $$a_{nk} = p_k(\lambda_0)q_n(\lambda_0) - q_k(\lambda_0)p_n(\lambda_0).$$

The author now claim the following and I am not sure the inequality that was used. Please see the image below[image]

Hints and suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for the first inequality the author is using
$$(a+b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2),$$
Or equivalently (just substitute $b$ eirh $-b$)
$$(a-b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2).$$
(You can easily check these inequalities by expanding the bracket)

The second inequality is trivial, although a priori one shiuld put $\leq$ instead of $<$)